# How do I get the JSON response from the image uploader vgy.me in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm implementing a small image uploading function in my web page, nothing too fancy, and to that end, I think vgy.me is a good tool. From what I understand, we can upload an image to the site via a `POST` method in a form. It returns a JSON response for every image uploaded, which contains a link to the image among other things (important because I intend to use that link for future purposes). There's even a helpful little example of the same on its API page ([link](https://vgy.me/api)).

My question is, how can I get that JSON response for my use using vanilla JavaScript? My initial searches have turned out techniques which pertain to server-side, which obviously I can't implement because it isn't my server I'm using. Is there a way to use the default `POST` method of HTML to get the JSON value, or perhaps I've misinterpreted the instructions?

I'm not using the jQuery code given on the page, because I've no knowledge of any JavaScript framework, and I'd rather not simply copy and paste if I could help it.

Comment: Post you code so we can see what you after and where is the problems. The community will not write the code for you

Comment: Sorry if I broke any rules, but I was simply wondering about a method which can be used to get a response from the API. I can't really figure out how can I get to that point, so I haven't really written any code. Does asking for explanations about an API violates the code of conduct of StackOverflow? I'm not asking for a written code, just an explanation of the API's method to get the required JSON response.

Comment: I should add that I've also linked to the API's page, which has an example code using a jQuery library I'm not familiar with. I was just wondering about an equivalent vanilla JavaScript code for fetching the JSON response. I hope that clears any doubts on the veracity of the question.